# Nature of restrictions on passing during niddah

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, niddah

I was taught before I got married that passing during niddah is strictly Assur.
However, Upon looking into it I found that it's not mentioned in the gemara in berachos that is the source for most of our Harchokos. It seems Rashi was the first to be makpid on it. I believe the Rambam makes no mention of it.

I have heard two reasons why it's assur to pass:
You may touch her. 
Passing leads to closeness.

I would like to know:

A) The earliest sources for it

B) Is it Halacha? Minhag? Chumrah?

C) Are there any circumstances where it doesn't apply?

P.S.- Some of you might say "C'mon passing is the easiest Halacha to keep."
I find that it's one of the most "annoying" to keep as it is constantly coming up. Especially in public or when eating a shabbos meal out.

Comment: Slightly related question (not in a duplicate manner): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80027/why-can-a-husband-eat-with-his-wife-who-is-a-niddah-in-public-without-a-heker

Comment: What do you mean by "passing"?

Comment: @DanF I think he's referring to passing objects from one to another.

Comment: [This footnote](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Harchakot_of_Niddah#cite_note-67) on halachipedia seems to imply that it's not that passing _leads_ to touching or that you might accidentally touch her, but rather that passing is _like_ touching. That would imply that the issur is just as strong as actually touching.

Comment: [Shulchan Arukh](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.195.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) brings this halacha directly.

Comment: @Daniel or does it being this custom directly?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, it's not a proof that it isn't on the level of minhag. Although he uses the word אסור which seems to indicate that it's at least on some level more stringent than "it is praiseworthy to be strict" like some of the other popular customs w.r.t. family purity.

Comment: "It seems Rashi was the first to be makpid on it": I doubt it. I mean, what are the chances? Probably _someone_ before him was.

Comment: I think we answered question A.

Comment: B & C are still out there. If  It's not a D'oraysa and there was no takana or gezeira forbidding it, then all these poskim are prohibiting it based off a minhag that started in Rashi's time?

Comment: I believe some poskim are mattir passing a baby as the baby is a choleh. I heard this in a shiur from R' Mordechai Willig.

Answer (score 11):

The [Talmud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) records the following story:

**[Shabbat 13a-13b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=13&format=pdf)**

> תני דבי אליהו מעשה בתלמיד א' ששנה הרבה וקרא הרבה ושימש תלמידי חכמים
>   הרבה ומת בחצי ימיו והיתה אשתו נוטלת תפיליו ומחזרתם בבתי כנסיות ובבתי
>   מדרשות ואמרה להם כתיב בתורה כי הוא חייך ואורך ימיך בעלי ששנה הרבה וקרא
>   הרבה ושימש תלמידי חכמים הרבה מפני מה מת בחצי ימיו ולא היה אדם מחזירה
>   דבר פעם אחת נתארחתי אצלה והיתה מסיחה כל אותו מאורע ואמרתי לה בתי בימי
>   נדותך מה הוא אצלך אמרה לי חס ושלום אפי' באצבע קטנה לא נגע [בי] בימי
>   לבוניך מהו אצלך אכל עמי ושתה עמי וישן עמי בקירוב בשר ולא עלתה דעתו על
>   דבר אחר ואמרתי לה ברוך המקום שהרגו שלא נשא פנים לתורה שהרי אמרה תורה
>   ואל אשה בנדת טומאתה לא תקרב
>
> [It is taught in the] Tanna debe Eliyahu: It once happened that a
>   certain scholar who had studied much Bible and Mishnah and had served
>   scholars much, yet died in middle age. His wife took his tefillin and
>   carried them about in the synagogues and schoolhouses and complained
>   to them, It is written in the Torah, for that is thy life, and the
>   length of thy days: my husband, who read [Bible], learned [Mishnah],
>   and served scholars much, why did he die in middle age? and no man
>   could answer her. On one occasion I was a guest at her house, and she
>   related the whole story to me. Said I to her, ‘My daughter! how was he
>   to thee in thy days of menstruation?’ ‘God forbid!’ she rejoined; ‘he
>   did not touch me even with his little finger.’ ‘And how was he to thee
>   in thy days of white [garments]?’ ‘He ate with me, drank with me and
>   slept with me in bodily contact, and it did not occur to him to do
>   other.’ Said I to her, ‘Blessed be the Omnipresent for slaying him,
>   that He did not condone on account of the Torah! For lo! the Torah
>   hath said, And thou shalt not approach unto a woman as long as she is
>   impure by her uncleanness.

[Tosafot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot) there mentions that [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) was נוהג איסור in regards to passing a key to his wife:

**[Tosafot Shabbat 13b S.V. Bimei](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=13b&format=pdf)**

> ורש"י היה נוהג איסור להושיט מפתח מידו לידה בימי נדותה

The term "נוהג איסור" is not the most precise of halachic categories. I would render it something to the effect of "he treated it like it was forbidden", implying that Rashi did not claim that it was outright prohibited but his minhag was to refrain from it.

Tosafot suggests basis for Rashi's practice from a parallel version of the Talmudic story (i.e. the story here which Tosafot is commenting on) found in the Midrash. In that version<sup>1</sup> Eliyahu asks the woman:

> שמא הבאת לו את השמן שמא הבאת לו את הפך
>
> Perhaps you brought him the oil, perhaps you brought him the jug?

This would apparently indicate that a niddah should not be bringing her husband the oil or the jug, i.e. she cannot pass things to him. However, Tosafos points out that the Midrash immediately continues with:

> ונגע ביך באצבע הקטנה

This would indicate that the only issue with passing something is if they actually touch, in which case there would be no support for Rashi's practice.

[R. Yaakov Ben Asher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher) codifies Rashi's practice:

**[Tur Y.D. 195](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5373)**

> ולא יושיט מידו לידה שום דבר ולא יקבלנו מידה
>
> One should not pass anything from his hand to her hand, nor receive
>   anything from her hand.

The language doesn't really specify what level of forbiddenness this is.

[R. Yosef Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) in his commentary there quotes rishonim that agree that one should be concerned for this, as well as rishonim that think that there is no such concern. The concern appears to be that when passing something, they might end up touching:

> ומ"ש ולא יושיט מידו לידה שום דבר ולא יקבלנו מידה בפ"ק דשבת ובפרק אף
>   על פי  כתבו התוספות שרש"י היה נזהר בכך מדאמרינן בסדר אליהו בההוא עובדא
>   דקרא ושנה הרבה ומת בחצי ימיו שאמר לו אליהו שמא הבאת לו את השמן שמא
>   הבאת לו את הפך והם ז"ל כתבו דאין משם ראיה וכן כתבו סמ"ג וספר התרומה
>   ואכתוב לשונם גבי כל מלאכות שאשה עושה לבעלה נדה עושה לבעלה והרא"ש בפרק
>   אף על פי כתב דשפיר יש ראיה משם למנהג רש"י והרב המגיד בפרק כ"א מהלכות
>   אישות דקדק מלשון הרמב"ם שכתב שנדה אינה נותנת הכוס ביד בעלה משמע ששאר
>   דברים יכולה היא להושיט מידה לידו וכן דעת קצת מפרשים ויש מחמירים בכל
>   דבר עכ"ל והרשב"א מן האוסרים שכתב  וז"ל לא יושיט מידו לידה שום דבר שמא
>   יגע בבשרה וז"ל רבינו ירוחם העידו על רש"י שלא היה רוצה לתת מפתח מידו
>   לידה וכן נכון להחמיר אפילו בדבר ארוך שמא לא יזהר בטוב ויגע בידה עכ"ל

[R. Moshe Isserles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) in his commentary there quotes the Beis Yosef and adds earlier sources who extend this practice to throwing things as well:

> וכתוב בבנימין זאב סימן קנ"ט ועל אותן המתירין לעצמן וזורקין מפתח או דבר
>   אחר מידו לידה וכו' ראוי לגעור בהן עכ"ל וכן הוא בשערי דורא בהגהות בשם
>   מהר"ם ז"ל

[R. Yehoshua Falk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Falk), however, seems to think that the Tur does not agree with this extension:

> [**Derisha Y.D. 195:4**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5377)
>
> ואסורה ליצוק לו מים לרחוץ בו פניו ידיו ורגליו אפילו אינה נוגעת בו. זה
>   לשון ב"י [כן כתבו] סמ"ג וסמ"ק והרשב"א דמיירי שהוא (רחוק) [רוחץ] והיא
>   מוצקת דאילו ליגע היא בידה אפילו בלי רחיצה אסור דהא איכא קירוב בשר
>   ואסור ליגע בה ואפילו באצבע קטנה עכ"ל ומוכח בהדיא מזה דבשעה שהוא רוחץ
>   היא מוצקת מרחוק על ידיו וכן מוכח מדברי רבינו שלא מיעט אלא הנגיעה
>   ולאפוקי מיש מפרשים שאמרו שבכהאי גוונא נמי לא איצטריך למימר דאסור דהא
>   אפילו שאר דברים אסור להשליך מידה לידו אפילו בלי נגיעה אלא מיירי הכא
>   שאסורה ליצוק לו מים תוך משיכלא ושהוא ירחץ בו וזה אינו דרבינו לא איירי
>   בהכי ויש לומר דבכהאי גוונא סבירא ליה דמותר ומה שכתב בש"ע וב"י הביאו
>   דאפילו בלא רחיצה אסור להשליך מיד ליד  אפשר שהאחרונים החמירו בזה והוא
>   לא החמיר כל כך א"נ מיירי הכא דמיקטף קטף למיא דלא נגעה אפילו על ידי
>   ניצוק ואפילו הכי אסור משום חיבת שימוש דרחיצה

R. Yosef Karo codifies the practice in the Shulchan Aruch, with the explanation that passing might cause touching, without mention of the extension to throwing. R. Moshe Isserles adds in the extension there:

**[Shulchan Aruch Y.D. 195:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5535)**

> ולא יושיט מידו לידה שום דבר ולא יקבלנו מידה שמא יגע בבשרה וכן על ידי
>   זריקה מידו לידה או להיפך אסור

[R. Mordechai Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe) codifies this practice as well, including the part about throwing, and mentions that it is because they might touch:

**[Levush Y.D. 195:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9276&st=&pgnum=224)**

> ולא יושיט מידו לידה שום דבר ולא יקבלנה מידה שמא יגע בבשרה ואפילו על
>   ידי זריקה מידו לידה או איפכא אסור

[R. Avraham Azulai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Azulai), in his glosses to the above statement of R. Mordechai Yaffe, cites an opinion that one need not be stringent regarding throwing unless it is done in a frivolous manner:

> וכתב הריק"ש ועל ידי זריקה אין להחמיר כל שאינו דרך שחוק

[R. Avraham Hirsch Eisenstadt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Hirsch_ben_Jacob_Eisenstadt_of_Byelostok) cites a dispute whether even throwing something indirectly is problematic (i.e. throwing it up in the air and the wife "happens" to catch it):

**[Pitchei Teshuva Y.D. 195:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5535)**

> עי' בשו"ת שבסוף ס' מנחת יעקב שכתב דאסור לאשה נדה להסיר מבעלה נוצה דרך
>   נפיחה ומביא ראיה מאמימר דשקיל גברא גדפא מיניה א"ל פסילנא לך לדינא ע"ש
>   ועי' בתשו' הר הכרמל חי"ד סי' י"ח שדחה זה והעלה להתיר ע"ש גם הכו"פ כתב
>   דאין להחמיר בזה עוד כתב שם שראה נוהגין שזורקין דבר כלפי מעלה ולא לנוכח
>   אשתו כמתכוין לזרוק לידה והיא פושטת ידה ומקבלתו ויש להקל בזה ע"ש [אכן
>   בס"ט כתב דאע"פ שיש להקל מעיקר הדין מ"מ אין להתיר וכל המחמיר בענינים
>   כאלה תע"ב ע"ש

[R. Yechiel Michel Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein), however, strongly writes that all forms of passing and throwing are forbidden.

**[Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 195:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&st=&pgnum=119)**

> לא יגע בה אפילו באצבע קטנה ולכן אסור לו ליתן לה דבר מידו לידה אפילו
>   דבר ארוך מפני חשש נגיעה ולא פלוג רבנן וכן לא יקבל מידה שום דבר מטעם זה
>   ואפילו לזרוק דבר מידו לידה או מידה לידו אסור בכל עניין בין שהזריקה הוא
>   במשך שוה בין שהזריקה למעלה או למטה אסור דהרחקה עבוד רבנן מפני שהוא עמה
>   בתדירות לכן צריך זהירות יתירה כדי שלא יכשלו

---

<sup>1. I have not found a Midrash with precisely the version quoted by Tosafot. However there are other similar versions with slightly different wording, for which Tosafot's point would still be applicable. For instance, Yalkut Shimoni in Parshat Metzora has שמא הבאת לו את הסכין שבידך ונגע בו אפילו באצבע הקטנה and Tanna Devei Eliyahu has שמא הסכתה לו את שמן בידך ונגע (בו) [ביך] אפילו באצבעו הקטנה.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your in-depth answer. I find it extremely intruiging that the Aruch Hashulchan says its a "lo Plug". That seems to imply there was a gezeira against passing while niddah. If you look in the Rambam hilchos issurei biah, at the end of perek 11, look at 18&19, The Rambam never mentions passing as an issur. In the Hagahas Maimonos on it (50) he brings that rashi wouldnt pass but he says clearly passing is muttar. Im very confused now how seemingly all major poskim say it's assur.

Comment: The Hagahos Maimonios is only citing an opinion that it is muttar. And the Rambam does discuss passing, just not in Issurei Biah. You have to look at Ishus 21:8 for that. (The Maggid Mishneh derives from the Rambam's wording there that passing is only a problem by a cup but not other things.) As for your confusion, it is not an infrequent occurrence that many poskim say something is assur while one says it's muttar (or just doesn't mention it).

Comment: @YitzyF Forgot to ping you in the above comment.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I've learned a lot of Halacha and I find this Halacha to be extremely perplexing. Yes, we have machloksim all over the place, in every area of Halacha. However, This situation is very unique- all orthodox jews hold that passing while niddah is strictly prohibited, under all circumstances, while we have yet to find anyone before Rashi's time that mentions it's assur. IT'S NOT D'ORAYSA. IT'S NOT A TAKANA OR GEZEIRA D'RABANUN. THE RAMBAM NEVER EVEN MENTIONS IT BY HARCHAKAS NIDDAH. But we all hold it's strictly assur???? Please help me understand how this came to be.

Comment: @YitzyF Probably because all the major codes after Rambam codified it (Tur, Shulchan Aruch, Levush, Aruch Hashulchan).

Comment: I always wondered what "codified it" means. That its an accepted minhag that now is binding? It can't be anything other than a minhag.

Comment: @yitzy so what if it's a Minhag? There are lots of Minhagim that everyone keeps. Why are you so surprised to find out that everyone keeps a certain Minhag?

Comment: @Double AA     Of course we have minhagim in every area of our lives that we all keep.I'm not surprised to find out that we all keep this. I'm surprised here about the level of stringency attached to it.  This isn't an easy minhag to follow. For couples trying to conceive, it applies to half their lives. For a couple after childbirth, it's usually 4-6 weeks. AND ITS SUPER INCONVENIENT! It can also be extremely embarrassing. (This can often create a very negative view of a mitzvah.) Now Yiddishkeit isn't always easy or conveneint. But if its not an issur drabanun, why do we have to keep it?

Comment: @Yitzy level of stringency?? Many people treat corn stricter than wheat on pesach! Some Minhagim are taken very seriously by people. I'm sure lots of not so committed Jews do skimp on this custom. But that's life. This isn't some uniquely different case that you should be seeking a special reason for what is ubiquitous in Judaism

Comment: I guess what I really have a hard time with is that minhag that everyone keeps= issur.