# What legislation requires a Jew to adhere to a precedent or Minhag

Tags: minhag

Under what commandment are we required to keep existing minhagim. What is the earliest source that requires minhag to be adhered to.

(An example that springs to mind is after the Beis Hamikdash was destroyed, the Jews in the Diaspora wanted to switch to keep only 1 day, and they were told to keep the minhag of their fathers. But perhaps that was not a requirement, merely advice.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a minhag become binding?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94198/how-can-a-minhag-become-binding)

Comment: I dont think so. That thread doesn't have answers which bring a legislative basis, it rather just states they must be adhered to.

Comment: See pesachim 50b

Comment: Beitzah 4b הִזָּהֲרוּ בְּמִנְהַג אֲבוֹתֵיכֶם בִּידֵיכֶם

Comment: @Yehuda At least two of the answers give a halachic basis.

Comment: @MichoelR not how I understand it. According to your understanding, what is the basis of the requirement? Min Hatorah? Miderabbanan? Neder?

Comment: @rosends how do you know this is Halacha, rather than advice? The language in fact suggests it isnt Halacha, otherwise stronger language may have been used

Comment: They bring the verse from Mishlei. What is the basis for assuming it's optional? When the Torah tells you to do something, you need to do it.

Comment: @MichoelR Mishlei advises many things as a way of life, yet many are not Halacha. Mishlei is not a Halacha sefer, for example: אַל־תְּהִ֣י חָכָ֣ם בְּעֵינֶ֑יךָ, is not a Halacha, but rather a way of life.

Comment: These Rishonim seem to disagree with you. Perhaps you ought to be shifting your question to something about how we can tell when Mishlei is giving an obligation.

Comment: @Yehuda the Rambam codifies is from this citation "אֲבָל תַּקָּנַת חֲכָמִים הוּא שֶׁיִּזָּהֲרוּ בְּמִנְהַג אֲבוֹתֵיהֶם שֶׁבִּידֵיהֶם" משנה תורה, הלכות קידוש החודש ה׳:ה׳

Comment: @rosends great find, that seems like an answer to me, I wonder if the Rambam held that all minhagim are Takanos Chachamim. Likely so.